# Spring MVC display uploaded image into a External Folder

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, image-uploading

I am creating a image uploading app using Spring mvc . I saved the image successfully in a external folder. Code for saving the image is like this:

```
  MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();

        path= Paths.get("/oms/images/"+product.getProductName()+".jpg");

        System.out.println(path.toString());
        if(productImage!=null && !productImage.isEmpty()){

            try {
                productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Product Image Saving Failed ",e);

            }
        }
```

Image is getting saved into that external folder successfully. But when I am trying to display the same image into a jsp file, I end up getting this error....

```
http://localhost:8081/oms/images/Ss.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8081/oms/images/pup.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

the code to display the image is like this...

```
  <img src="<c:url value="/oms/images/${product.productName}.jpg"/>"/>
```

I saw some more couple of links for the same issue, but mostly question are like to save images into a different directory than webapp (obviously)!

Am I missing something? How to add  external resources into Spring? What should I do to display user added uploaded images into jsp page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above solution didn't work for me. If I tried calling **@WebServlet("/FetchFile")** from the jsp page, **@WebServlet("/FetchFile")** didn't even get invoked . I Googled it and found a solution that in spring mvc dispatcher-servlet.xml we can add a external resource in this way:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:///${fullPath}/oms/images/" />
```

**${fullPath}**   you should give your full path here:

then from jsp page you can invoke the jsp file like this:

```
<img src="/images/${product.productName}.jpg" alt="image"/>
```

After full day I finally got the solution and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a servlet to retrieve images outside webcontext as jsp code will only work within web context.
As an example

```
@WebServlet("/FetchFile")
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String filename = request.getParameter("productName");
        File file = new File("/oms/images/"+filename);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(filename));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```

and request it using

```
<img scr="FetchFile?productName=${product.productName}.jpg">
```

Comment: you mean I should add this method to spring controller and then from jsp page i should make a call to this method ?

Comment: Yes ! That would be an ajax call by nature

Comment: I did ... i copied the class file and I am trying to access it by ..  <td> <img scr="FetchFile?productName=${product.productName}.jpg" alt="image"/> </td> ....   but not working for me ... I put syso also in that class file looks like that file is not getting invoked also ...what's wrong ? I am using tomcat 7 and tomcat 8 also ... same result .. what can be the issue  @WebServlet("/FetchFile") is not getting invoked . I am not getting any error in browser console. Can you please check this ?

Comment: Thanks @Rizstien  .. finally this worked for me ...                                              <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:///${fullPath}/oms/images/" />

Comment: sorry there was some problem may be i couldn't view your complete comment. The problem was the servlet mapping technique, may be that was not working with your configurations. the idea was to make a servlet and   download resource from it

Comment: Yes .. I checked it and it was correct but it was not working with my spring-mvc configuration . by the way thanks for helping me :)